# source in subshell doesn't work as expected

Tags: bash

I've noticed something odd in bash.
Let's suppose I have a file toto containing the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
export foo=2
```

if I run `source toto; echo foo=$foo` , I get as expected

> foo=2

However, if I run `bash -c "source toto; echo foo=$foo"`, I get

> foo=

Same thing if I run

```
bash << EOF
source toto
echo foo=$foo
EOF
```

Still, If I create a file test.sh containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo foo=$foo
```

And then I run `bash -c "source toto; ./test.sh"` then I finally get the expected

> foo=2

Does someone understand these results? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run

```
bash -c "source toto; echo foo=$foo"
```

the shell you're typing into expands all the variables in the string. At that time, `$foo` doesn't yet have a value, so it's as if you'd written

```
bash -c "source toto; echo foo="
```

If you use single quotes instead of double quotes, variables are not expanded. Then the literal command line is sent to `bash`, and it will expand `$foo` itself.

```
bash -c 'source toto; echo foo=$foo'
```

See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)